# Multiple networks in one simulation (how configure ini)

Tags: networking, ini, omnet++

I have two networks. For example I use tutorial `Tictok1` and `Tictok2` In one `.ned` file. How can I run It in one simulation? I tried find solution in google for last two days.

I was tried config like:

```
[General]
network = Tictoc1,Tictoc2
```

or

```
[General]
network = Tictoc1;Tictoc2
```

The tictoc1.ned file:

```
simple Txc1
{
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}


simple Txc2
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing"); // add a default icon
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}
network Tictoc1
{
    submodules:
        tic: Txc1;
        toc: Txc1;
    connections:
        tic.out --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> toc.in;
        tic.in <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
}

network Tictoc2
{
    submodules:
        tic: Txc2 {
            parameters:
                @display("i=,cyan"); // do not change the icon (first arg of i=) just colorize it
        }
        toc: Txc2 {
            parameters:
                @display("i=,gold"); // here too
        }
    connections:
        tic.out --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> toc.in;
        tic.in <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
}
```

I want to now Is possible do that and how do it. Of course I can do:

```
[General]
[Config Tictoc1]
network = Tictoc1
[Config Tictoc2]
network = Tictoc2
```

But this will start separate simulations. I need this two in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OMNeT++ there is no way to use more than one network simultaneously.
 However, you can achieve your goal treating each your network as a compound module. In the `tictoc1.ned` just change:

- `network Tictoc1` into `module Tictoc1`
- `network Tictoc2` into `module Tictoc2`

and add at the end of `tictoc1.ned`:

```
network TicTocNet {
    submodules:
      network1: Tictoc1;
      network2: Tictoc2;
}
```

In `omnetpp.ini` set:

```
[General]
[Config TicTocNet]
network = TicTocNet
```

Comment: Yeah, this solution indeed works, however I don't see why OP really wants to do this. IMHO, it is meaningless. At least, in the last 15 years I'm working with OMNeT++, nobody asked for this :)

Comment: This works, like you wrote. Thanks,that very helpful, Pozdrawiam z Warszawy :)

Comment: @Rudi this is helpful whe you wany simulate 802.11af and RFID - Viatol systems. I need this to my master’s dissertation :)

Comment: Ok, I reformulate this: In omnet the top level compound module is called 'network'. As soon as you want to run 'two networks', you actually run two compound modules, and you have a top level module which contains them. From that point that is the network...

Anyway, this is just semantics and naming ;) You can run any number of modules parallel this way, that the beauty of composeability  in OMNeT++